# Wait for change of prop from parent component after changing it from a child in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have rewritten a Child class component in React to a functional component. Here is the simplified code example.

For sure, as so often, this is a simplified code and more things are done with the value in the parent component. That's why we have and need it there.

```js
const Parent = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

  const handleChange = (newValue) => {
    // do something with newValue and probably change it
    // store the result in `newChangedValue`
    setValue(newChangedValue);
  }

  return (
    <Child value={value} onChange={handleChange}/>
  );
}

const Child = (props) => {
  const {value} = props;

  // This solution does not work for me,
  // because it's always triggered, when
  // `value` changes. I only want to trigger
  // `logValueFromProp` after clicking the
  // Button.
  useEffect(() => {
    logValueFromProp();
  }, [value]);

  const handleClick = () => {
    // some calculations to get `newValue`
    // are happening here
    props.onChange(newValue);
    logValueFromProp();
  }

  const logValueFromProp = () {
    console.log(prop.value);
  }

  return (
    <Button onClick={handleClick} />
  );
}
```

What I want to do is to log a properties value, but only if it got changed by clicking the button. So just using a `useEffect` does not work for me.

Before changing the child component to a functional component, the property had its new value before I was calling `logValueFromProp()`. Afterwards it doesn't. I guess that's cause of some timing, and I was just lucky that the property was updated before the function was called.

So the question is: How would you solve this situation? One solution I thought of was a state in the child component which I set when the button is clicked and in the useEffect I only call the function when the state is set and then reset the state. But that doesn't feel like the optimal solution to me...

Comment: Can't you just pass `newValue` directly to `logValueFromProp` instead of using `prop.value`?

Comment: ^^ that's how I would do it, for what it's worth.

Comment: In this example, I could. But I don't know what will happen with the value in the parent component. It might change to something else than just being the value. I'll update the example to include that case in the example.

Comment: Ah, so you want to log the value _after_ the parent has had a chance to make changes to it, but only if the changes were originally triggered by this button click?

Comment: @UncleDave exactly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It's a simplified code example, and that part is not really my problem. But I'll fix the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Three possible solutions for you

1. Pass `logValueFromProp` the value directly — but in a comment you've explained that the value might be modified slightly by the parent component before being set on the child, which would make this not applicable.
2. Use a flag in a ref. But if the parent doesn't always change the prop, that would be unreliable.
3. Have the parent accept a callback in its `handleChange`.

#### #1

If possible, I'd pass the value directly to `logValueFromProp` when you want to log it. That's the simple, direct solution:

```
const Child = (props) => {
  const {value} = props;

  const handleClick = () => {
    props.onChange(newValue);
    logValueFromProp(newValue);
  };

  const logValueFromProp = (newValue = prop.value) {
    console.log(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <Button onClick={handleClick} />
  );
};
```

But in a comment you've said the new value may not be exactly the same as what you called `props.onChange` with.

#### #2

You could use a `ref` to remember whether you want to log it when the component function is next called (which will presumably be after it changes):

```
const Child = (props) => {
  const {value} = props;
  const logValueRef = useRef(false);

  if (logValueRef.current) {
    logValueFromProp();
    logValueRef.current = false;
  }

  const handleClick = () => {
    props.onChange(newValue);
    logValueRef.current = true;
  };

  const logValueFromProp = () {
    console.log(prop.value);
  };

  return (
    <Button onClick={handleClick} />
  );
};
```

Using a ref instead of a state member means that when you clear the flag, it doesn't cause a re-render. (Your component function is only called after `handleClick` because the parent changes the `value` prop.)

Beware that if the parent component **doesn't** change the value when you call `prop.onChange`, the ref flag will remain set and then your component will mistakenly log the next changed value even if it isn't from the button. For that reason, it might make sense to try to move the logging to the parent, which knows how it responds to `onChange`.

#### #3

Given the issues with both of the above, the most robust solution would seem to be to modify `Parent`'s `handleChange` so that it calls a callback with the possibly-modified value:

```
const Parent = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

  const handleChange = (newValue, callback) => {
    //                          ^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− ***
    // do something with newValue and probably change it
    // store the result in `newChangedValue`
    setValue(newChangedValue);
    if (callback) {                                      // ***
        callback(newChangedValue);                       // ***
    }                                                    // ***
  };

  return (
    <Child value={value} onChange={handleChange}/>
  );
};

const Child = (props) => {
  const {value} = props;

  const handleClick = () => {
    props.onChange(newValue, logValueFromProp);
    //                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−− ***
  }

  const logValueFromProp = () {
    console.log(prop.value);
  };

  return (
    <Button onClick={handleClick} />
  );
};
```

Comment: The final proposal seems like a winner to me.

Comment: Thank you for the solutions. I guess #3 would be the most robust way, as you said. They all look interesting though.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based upon the [answer of T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69361594/3982562) (#2).

You can create a custom hook that accepts a callback and dependencies. And returns a function that will trigger a re-render (by using `useState` instead of `useContext`) calling the callback in the process.

I've enhanced his answer by allowing you to pass a dependency array which will be used to determine if the callback is called. If the dependency array is omitted, the callback is always called. When passed, the callback is only called if there was a change in the dependency array.

I went for the name `useTrigger` in the example below, but depending on preference you might like another name better. For example `useChange`.

```js
const { useState, useCallback } = React;

const useTrigger = (function () {
  function zip(a1, a2) {
    return a1.map((_, i) => [a1[i], a2[i]]);
  }
  
  // compares 2 arrays assuming the length is the same
  function equals(a1, a2) {
    return zip(a1, a2).every(([e1, e2]) => Object.is(e1, e2));
  }
  
  return function (callback, deps) {
    const [trigger, setTrigger] = useState(null);
    
    if (trigger) {
      if (!deps || !equals(deps, trigger.deps)) {
        callback(...trigger.args);
      }
      setTrigger(null);
    }
    
    return useCallback((...args) => {
      setTrigger({ args, deps });
    }, deps);
  }
})();

function Parent() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  
  function handleChange(newValue) {
    // Sometimes the value is changed, triggering `logValueFromProp()`.
    // Sometimes it isn't.
    if (Math.random() < 0.66) newValue++;
    setValue(newValue);
  }

  return <Child value={value} onChange={handleChange} />;
}

function Child({ value, onChange }) {
  const logValueFromProp = useTrigger(() => {
    console.log(value);
  }, [value]);

  function handleClick() {
    onChange(value || 0);
    logValueFromProp();
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>
      Click Me!
    </button>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.querySelector("#demo"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="demo"></div>
```